# How to reference same user inputted range across multiple sheets

Tags: excel, vba, select, range

I am trying to delete all the empty rows across all worksheets in a workbook. I've put together the following code but it only seems to work on the active sheet. I'm struggling to determine why it isn't applying across all sheets with my for loop. Any advice is appreciated

```
Sub deleteemptyrows()
  Dim r As Range, rows As Long, i As Long, ws As Worksheet
  Set r = Application.InputBox( _
  Title:="Macro Cell Range", _
  Prompt:="Select range you would like to delete", _
  Type:=8)



  On Error GoTo 0
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets

        rows = r.rows.Count
        For i = rows To 1 Step (-1)
            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(r.rows(i)) = 0 Then r.rows(i).Delete

        Next
    Next ws

End Sub
```

Comment: Because `r` is the `Range` on the worksheet selected when the `InputBox` was used. You can use `r.Address` with each worksheet.

Comment: @BigBen magic bad, deleting comment

Answer (score 1):

```
Sub deleteemptyrows()
    Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range, strt As Long, stp As Long, i As Long
    On Error Resume Next
    Set rng = Application.InputBox("Select range you would like to delete", "Macro Cell Range", Type:=8)
    strt = rng(1).Row: stp = strt + rng.rows.Count
    For Each ws In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets
        For i = stp To strt Step (-1)
            If WorksheetFunction.CountA(ws.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow) = 0 Then ws.Cells(i, 1).EntireRow.Delete
        Next
    Next ws
End Sub
```

Comment: well, he did, so I assumed he wanted to include that.

Comment: According to you, it's not a part of the question. If you want to make your answer more dynamic, feel free.

Comment: very true, but lastRow should be based on something

Comment: Yeah that's pretty basic, but then you have to assume a column or vastly lengthen the code